# Getting "Open DataReader" error from in-memory List in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, linq, parallel.foreach

My apologies if this has been asked but I'm running `Parallel.Foreach` to speed up business logic and passing in 4 partitions of `List<item>`.

A particular query on an in-memory list is throwing a **"The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."** error and when continuing through a **"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"** error. The list is in-memory from an earlier database call before the `Parallel.Foreach` code and that database call is ended with a `ToList()` (closing the connection I believe).

I thought errors like this were from making database calls in parallel, so I'm wondering what I'm missing here. Here's the *LINQ* query throwing the error:

```
List<item> itemList= Items.Where(m => m.Property1?.Property2 == specificValue).ToList();
```

Parallel.ForEach setup/code

```
//There are four 'chunks' of about 500 items each
Parallel.ForEach(chunks, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, chunk =>{
foreach (Case cas in chunk)
{
    List<item> itemList= Items.Where(m => m.Property1?.Property2 == 
    cas.Id).ToList();
    ...other business logic
}

}
```

Comment: If you're using EF, you can't do concurrent db calls.

Comment: That makes sense, but the list above called itemList is an in-memory List. It was generated once by a database call, and that db call was outside of the Parallel code.

Comment: You'll have to do what Theodor said and post because you have some open data reader based on the error message.

Comment: Sure, one minute. I need to remove some sensitive code, but can show you what the overall item looks like.

Comment: Note if `Items` is an IEnumerable, but not a List or Array, enumerating it may re-run the database query.  IE `var Items = db.Set<Item>().OrderBy(i = i.Name)` Items is _not_ an in-memory collection.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Gotcha, that Items variable is an explicit List, so I'm guessing it's not re-running the database query going off your comment about IEnumerables.  That List does come from a db call, but it prepended with .ToList() and is outside of the Parallel code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is indeed because you are making database calls in parallel. I assume you are using Entity Framework (EF) and have the default as "Lazy Loading" from the DB. Even after the `.ToList()` if any related items were not being used it hasn't loaded them from the DB yet.

The `Parallel.ForEach()` will execute your `Items.Where().ToList()` for all "4 chunks" concurrently. Since the `.Where()` requires item properties for comparison it will finally load from the DB. So its attempting to make 4 DB connections concurrently and with EF you can't have concurrent DB calls.

You should try "Eager Loading" the `Items` before the `Parallel.ForEach`.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/eager-loading-lazy-loading-and-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework/

Comment: I haven't heard that before but that makes sense. I will give that a shot and mark as answer shortly.

Comment: So a few lines beneath the itemList instantiation, there's a foreach iteration over that same list that's causing the same "connection was not closed" error
The foreach is iterating over the previous list as such:

 foreach (string entry in itemList.Where(m => m.BudgetId != null && m.Budget != null).Select(m => m.Budget.Name).Distinct())

Is this basically the same issue you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: It is a similar situation in that its caused by lazy loading. To be honest some of the internal logic of lazy loading in EF is unknown to me, its a complicated subject, and many just disable it. In your case I assume that `Budget` is a child entity (from another table) of `Item` which has yet to be lazy loaded. The `.Where()` is checking if `m.Budget` is not null, and I believe it might fetch from DB at that time, but then you also do `.Select()` to get the distinct `m.Budget.Name` which may be fetching the full budget object with the same DB connection causing the issue.

Comment: You can prevent that by eager loading `Budget` with your `Items`.

Comment: Avoid nested queries like `.Where().Select().Distinct()`. You might also have some luck setting MultipleActiveResultSets=True.

Comment: Just by using eager loading, my query went from timing out for end users (taking over 2-3 minutes locally) to running in about 15 seconds and that's not even using any parallelism so it must have been dinging the database hard. Thank you so much!

Comment: Right, the main side effect of lazy loading is more DB activity which can negatively impact DB performance, but less data in transit and less memory required. The main side effect to eager loading is more memory usage and more data in transit, but less DB activity which can improve DB performance. Glad I can help.